# Composer TransportException translation file could not be written

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am installing laravel 4 and running "composer install" command. It was able to install 13 packages successfully, but when it came time to install symfony/translation, it downloaded it 100% and then threw an error:

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/Translation/zipball/6bc4b753c1ae5640c0eacdbe27c04a69cde3d10d" appears broken, and returned an empty 200 response

Could it be because the original is 0 bytes? Is there a work around to installing this package?

Comment: It can not be because the original is not zero bytes. If it was zero bytes when you checked it some hours ago, then this was a problem with github not successfully delivering the file. If so, then the error message by composer was correct. If not, please say so to have this noted here.

Answer (score 9):

Dropping in to confim that I'm seeing this too so I guess I can stop panicking now as it seems to be an error somewhere between Packagist and Github (still a problem to my boss but something to be said for it not being your fault!)

edit: I'm having this issue with kriswallsmith / assetic running Symfony 2.1.9

update: Received an email from Github support indicating this is an issue that they are aware of and are actively looking into it.

I've just added the '--prefer-source' flag until the issue is resolved on their end.

Comment: Confirming that --prefer-source works as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem for twitter bootstrap:

```
[Composer\Downloaded\TransportException]
The "https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/v2.3.1" file could not be written to /my/path/Symfony/vendor/twitter/bootstrap/e01f28f3c03a11c104bae8d4a1b59d21.1:
```

Doing "composer self-update" changed it to:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
"https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/v2.3.1" appears broken, and returned an empty 200 response
```

Using "composer update --prefer-source" seems to have installed it properly.

So it looks like github zip file download is broken.

Comment: `--prefer-source` works because instead of downloading a zip package, it uses git to fetch the files. Check status of the diverse systems of github via their website: https://status.github.com/messages